# php get string each character

Tags: php, arrays, character-encoding

When I run the below code, I get `?` instead of first character which is `Ş`.

If i don't use any Turkish characters, I don't have any problem but when I use this characters which is `Ş,İ,Ö,Ç` I'm having problems.

```
$str = "Şef";
echo $str[0];
```

or

```
$str="Şef"; 
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) 
    echo  $str[$i] . '<br>';
```

How can resolve this problem? The header charset and HTML charset is utf-8 and my texteditor charset is utf-8 too.

Comment: UTF encoding in php...http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: I suggest you to use my solution, which has better performance, link: [`iconv vs mbstring_substr`](http://evertpot.com/iconv_substr-vs-mbstring_substr/). By the way, it is suggest calculate length before for loop instead of calculate if in loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use `Multibyte String Functions` 
http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

$str="Şef"; 

$len = mb_strlen($str);

for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    echo  mb_substr($str, $i, 1) . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`strlen()`](http://php.net/strlen) function and `[]` syntax work on a byte resolution. Characters like `Ş` are encoded in multiple bytes (2 to 4) in UTF-8. You have to use utf-8 compatible functions for it. PHP has 3 extensions for handling unicode.

### ext/intl

Most modern and suggested extension:

```
$str = "Şef"; 
$length = grapheme_strlen($str);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  echo  grapheme_substr($str, $i, 1).'<br>';
}
```

### ext/iconv

A standard extension (since PHP 5.0 *afaik*) [Demo](http://3v4l.org/Zr8DH)

```
$str = "Şef"; 
$length = iconv_strlen($str, 'utf-8');
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  echo  iconv_substr($str, $i, 1, 'utf-8').'<br>';
}
```

### ext/mbstring

Often installed extension, more functions then ext/iconv.

```
$str = "Şef"; 
$length = mbstring_strlen($str, 'utf-8');
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  echo  mbstring_substr($str, $i, 1, 'utf-8').'<br>';
}
```

Comment: this and srain answers solution my problem.  Which answers performance  is better ? thank you for answers

Comment: @user3021792, first. `mb_substr` performance better than `iconv_substr`; second, do not calculate length in for loop.